# How to combine both the queries mentioned here?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here i have two tables named `main_table` and `main_table_replica`. `main_table_replica` is replica of `main_table`. but the problem is i can find data either in `main_table` or `main_table_replica`. 
Now i am doing query as below. How can i avoid union here? In both the queries the only change is `main_table` and `main_table_replica`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id
         FROM
             main_table e,   //Change is here
             main_table_join_one x     
             where  e.some_id = x.some_id(+)
             and (x.status in('A','I') or x.status is null)
             and e.code='XYZ' and e.second_code in('XYZ','ABC')


             UNION

        SELECT DISTINCT t.some_id
         FROM
             main_table_replica t,   //Change is here
             main_table_join_one xf     
             where  t.some_id = xf.some_id(+)
             and (xf.status in('A','I') or xf.status is null)
             and t.code='XYZ' and t.second_code in('XYZ','ABC')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of this query?  What do you expect as the result?  What's wrong with using `UNION`?

Comment: I think is the duplication of code what he cares of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting stuff from two different tables in this fashion is exactly what `union` is for.  There is no reason to avoid it.

However, you could reduce the scope of the union to reduce duplication:

```
select distinct combined.some_id from (
        select e.some_id from main_table e
            union
        select t.some_id from main_table_replica t
    ) combined
    inner join  main_table_join_one x on
        combined.some_id = x.some_id(+) and
        (x.status in('A','I') or x.status is null) and
        combined.code='XYZ' and 
        combined.second_code in('XYZ','ABC');
```